# Match 2 values on excel / calc

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc, vlookup

I have this table structured as described below with some data for example:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| name1 | code2 | data3 | name4 | code5 | 
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| aaaaa | 11111 | x1    | aaaaa | 11111 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| bbbbb | 22222 | y1    | ddddd | 44444 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| ccccc | 33333 | z1    | ccccc | 33333 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| ddddd | 44444 | x2    | 
+-------+-------+-------+
| eeeee | 55555 | y2    |
+-------+-------+-------+
| fffff | 66666 | z2    | 
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Is it possible to look for data using matched data:
I would like to get the data from `data3` based on `name1` and `code2` data matched with the data on `name4` and `code5` so that the name4 and code5 columns data will be looked on the other columns...

Tried something but it didn't worked:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(name4,code5,$B:$B, 0)), "NF", VLOOKUP(name1,code2,$B:$C,2,0))
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Could you provide a step-by-step example, using the data that you've provided, to show what you want?

Comment: Do you want a [multiple criteria `Index/Match`](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/)?

Comment: I want to match data from columns 4-5 with 1-2 to extract data from 3...

Answer (score 1):

This formula in F2 will do what you're asking:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(D2,A:A,0)=MATCH(E2,B:B,0),INDEX(C:C,MATCH(D2,A:A,0)),"No Match"),"Not Found")
```

It provides two different messages for the cases where 1) D & E don't match A & B, and 2) where no match was found for one of the search terms.

[image]